# Programmatically clearing cache from OutputCacheAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

In our code we have an MVC controller action that is decorated with the `OutputCacheAttribute`. Is there any way in some other action to clear the cache for the first action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If it is a child action the cache is stored in the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) and the only way to clear it is undocumented and involves busting the whole memory cache:

```
OutputCacheAttribute.ChildActionCache = new MemoryCache("NewDefault");
```

The drawback of course is that this removes all cached child actions and not just the cached output of this child action. If it is a normal action then you could use the [Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.removeoutputcacheitem.aspx) method by passing it the url of the action that was cached. You might also find the [following article](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3) interesting.

Caching in ASP.NET MVC 3 has still a very long way to go. Hopefully they are improving many things in ASP.NET MVC 4 and simplifying it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to check out that article.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible
I have found the answer in [this book](http://www.scribd.com/doc/61582432/110/OutputCache-in-ASP-NET-MVC?). 
See 14.3 Output Cache In ASP.NET MVC 
page 372 - Deterministically removing items from cache

> When we decorate an action with the OutputCacheAttribute , OutputCache
>   stores its result into  ASP.NET Cache and automatically recovers it
>   when it must serve a subse- quent analogous request. If we knew which
>   cache key the page belongs to, we could easily remove it.
>   Unfortunately, this isn’t easily possible, and even if it were, we
>   aren’t  supposed to know it because it resides in the internal logic
>   of the caching infrastruc- ture and might change without notice in
>   future releases. What we can do, though, is leverage the cache
>   dependencies mechanism to achieve a similar result. This feature is
>   similar to the change monitors we’re going to talk about in section
>   14.4. Leveraging cache dependencies consists of tying one cache entry to another to automatically remove the first one when the latter is invalidated.

And a piece of code

```
public class DependencyOutputCacheAttribute : OutputCacheAttribute
{
public string ParameterName { get; set; }
public string BasePrefix { get; set; }

public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  base.OnResultExecuting( filterContext );

  string key = string.IsNullOrEmpty( BasePrefix )
                 ? filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"] + "_" + filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
                 : BasePrefix;

  key = AddToCache( filterContext, key, ParameterName);
}

private string AddToCache(ResultExecutingContext filterContext, string key, string parameter)
{
  if ( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( parameter ) && filterContext.RouteData.Values[parameter] != null) {
    key += "/" + filterContext.RouteData.Values[parameter];
    filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.AddBig( key, key );
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AddCacheItemDependency( key );   
  }
  return key;
}
}
```

And Remove cache dependency attribute

```
public class RemoveCachedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
public string ParameterName { get; set; }
public string BasePrefix { get; set; }
public override void OnResultExecuting( ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
  string key = string.IsNullOrEmpty(BasePrefix) ?
  filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString() + "_" +
  filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() : BasePrefix;
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParameterName))
    key += filterContext.RouteData.Values[ParameterName];
  filterContext.HttpContext.Cache.Remove(key);
}
}
```

and finally use it

```
    [DependencyCache( BasePrefix = "Story", ParameterName = "id" )]
public virtual ActionResult ViewStory(int id){
//load story here
}

[HttpPost, RemoveCache( BasePrefix = "Story", ParameterName = "id" )]
public virtual ActionResult DeleteStory(int id){
//submit updated story version
}

[HttpPost, RemoveCache( BasePrefix = "Story", ParameterName = "id" )]
public virtual ActionResult EditStory(Story txt){
//submit updated story version
}
```

where

```
public class Story { 
  int id {get;set;} //case is important
  string storyContent{get;set;}
}
```